# add http request header to http request header from openwrt

Tags: openwrt

All the http traffics from my openwrt router are now redirected to a proxy server http://proxyserver:7117.

I want to add a custom http request header to every http request so the proxy server can know the source router from which the traffics are originated.

Instead of installing proxy packages in the local openwrt, is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Openwrt knows nothing about http traffic in general configuration. My suggestion is: You should adjust iptables to redirect all http traffic(80,8080,etc.) to a local proxy which can modify http headers and then retransmits all modified packages to the remote proxy server. Try this local proxy server: http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/proxy.privoxy

And here is an example you need:
http://www.privoxy.org/user-manual/actions-file.html#ADD-HEADER

! This solution only for http traffic (not https)

Comment: is there a way to inject something like id to the https traffic?

Comment: There is no easy way to do it in a 5 minutes. You can try to dig into https spec, keys exchanging, certificates verification, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do it in Python but I am not sure if it suits you.

In case it helps:
use **urllib2** library and append the header as follows (for example):

`import urllib2
request = urllib2.Request("http://proxyserver:7117")
request.add_header("Source-router", "router_1")
urllib2.urlopen(request,`**actual data**`)`

**add_header(key, value)** method: https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.Request.add_header